# ISP, WiFi, Tracking

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services, anonymity, security, fingerprinting

I run Tor on my laptop and my phone. I have Verizon Wireless for a service provider. My laptop Internet connection is tethered through my cell phone. So I just run Tor on my laptop. Can Verizon or any other ISP track browsing history or searches? All of Tor's options are default. Some sites won't load or freeze when I access them. Plus I don't think I have Java enabled. I can't run any videos. I haven't looked into that setting yet.

Comment: Thanks for the question! I've closed this as a duplicate; please see the other question for answers (I know your question was here first, but the other one was a bit more clear and concise; it seemed to me the better one to direct users too). Don't be discouraged; this isn't a reprimand, just a way to ensure that all the best answers get aggrigated in one place. For more info, see the "duplicate questions" section under the "[Closed questions](http://tor.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)" help center article. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

No, they cannot do that, since all traffic is run through tor. 
Only way they can find that info is by compromising your laptop. 
You are as safe as any other tor user.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using the default settings of Tor, most scripts are disabled by default (including JavaScript) by a browser add-on called NoScript. Yes enabling JavaScript would allow you to watch movies, but you'd also make yourself vulnerable to people finding out information that could be used to identify you.